# Javascript to show html paje in shadow box Once

Tags: javascript, html, popup, shadowbox, jquery-cookie

am trying to do that using javascript i want to show HTML page in shadow box ONLY ONE TIME when visit the site using cookies how i can do that ? HTML page ready but i want to know how to show it in shadow box using javascript ONE time when the user visit the site ??

if you can help me to show html page in shadow box only that great

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
#ShadowBox {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    display: block;
    background-color: blue;
    display:none;
}
</style>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
// function for clearing the cookkie
$("#ClearCookie").click(function(){
    ClearCookie('visited');
});


//function for settinf the cookie
function setCookie(cname, cvalue, exdays) {
    var d = new Date();
    d.setTime(d.getTime() + (exdays * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000));
    var expires = "expires=" + d.toGMTString();
    document.cookie = cname + "=" + cvalue + "; " + expires;
}

//function for reading cookie
function getCookie(cname) {
    var name = cname + "=";
    var ca = document.cookie.split(';');
    for (var i = 0; i < ca.length; i++) {
        var c = ca[i].trim();
        if (c.indexOf(name) == 0) return c.substring(name.length, c.length);
    }
    return "";
}
//For Setting the Cookie, you can call this onload or at the displaying of the shadowbox.
function MarkVisited() {
    setCookie("visited", "visited", 10)
}

function ClearCookie(cname) {
    setCookie("visited", "", 1)
}


//Put this in the document ready section. so it runs at onload
$( document ).ready(function() {
if (getCookie('visited') == "") {
    $('#ShadowBox').show();
}
MarkVisited();
});
// On Load Section End
</script>
</head>

<body>
<div id="ShadowBox">
</div>
<button id="ClearCookie">Clear Cookie</button>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set a cookie when shadow box is displayed

Here is fiddle i have worked on http://jsfiddle.net/gd7Xz/
Working Fiddle of your Code http://jsfiddle.net/G3XAb/

Hope this Helps you, Please tick the Answer

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

    <head>
        <style>
            #ShadowBox {
                width: 100px;
                height: 100px;
                display: block;
                background-color: blue;
                display:none;
            }
        </style>
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script>
            //function for settinf the cookie
            function setCookie(cname, cvalue, exdays) {
                var d = new Date();
                d.setTime(d.getTime() + (exdays * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000));
                var expires = "expires=" + d.toGMTString();
                document.cookie = cname + "=" + cvalue + "; " + expires;
            }

            //function for reading cookie
            function getCookie(cname) {
                var name = cname + "=";
                var ca = document.cookie.split(';');
                for (var i = 0; i < ca.length; i++) {
                    var c = ca[i].trim();
                    if (c.indexOf(name) == 0) return c.substring(name.length, c.length);
                }
                return "";
            }
            //For Setting the Cookie, you can call this onload or at the displaying of the shadowbox.
            function MarkVisited() {
                setCookie("visited", "visited", 10)
            }

            function ClearCookie(cname) {
                setCookie(cname, "", 1)
            }


            //Put this in the document ready section. so it runs at onload
            $(document).ready(function() {
                if (getCookie('visited') == "") {
                    $('#ShadowBox').show();
                }
                MarkVisited();
            });
            // On Load Section End
        </script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <div id="ShadowBox"></div>
        <button id="ClearCookie" onClick="ClearCookie('visited')">Clear Cookie</button>
    </body>

</html>
```

Comment: this script set cookie and read it and check if the user visit or not but if its first time will show the shadowbox if not ???
where is the statement

Comment: Lolz, i just gave you the idea, you want the whole code. Okay wait.

Comment: Check the answer, i have added the fiddle, Please tick the answer, if it helps you.

Comment: when i move it to my local page .html its not showing anything just the button i tried to clear the cookies and still the same

Comment: did you put the on load section in the document ready section

Comment: amd most of alll have you added jQuery to your page

Comment: answer is been updated and working fiddle of your code is been adeed. Pleasea tick the answer :)